# What are the financial decisions leading to "barn find" automobiles?

Tags: united-states, car

Where I live there are laws against leaving vehicles to rot in one's backyard or dumping them in the forest, mostly to prevent soil pollution and the junkyard appearance. I understand different countries have different sensitivities towards pollution and the environment.

But I'm really curious about the financial aspects of people buying cars and leaving them to rot for decades on their property. It seems to be quite frequent in the USA, see for example [Hagerty's "Barn find hunter" show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePrBt0SeSmQ).

Among these cars are some that were wrecks when they were "stored", but there are also ones that were running and intact, but were simply abandoned. How come the owner decided to simply let a piece of property (some of them not cheap! exotic Italian cars and all) turn to dust?

I understand that buying cars, especially exotic or rare ones, and storing them for the long term is a form of investment. But their values are orders of magnitude higher if they are in good condition. Most of the carcasses seen on this show have zero residual value.

So, what are the financial motivations of people who buy cars and leave them to rot?

**Edit:** one thing I might be overlooking is that in the mid-20th century America, cars were crazy abundant and not very reliable so they had a pretty low second-hand value. As such they were effectively already worthless when they were parked and abandoned by their owners.

Comment: Not sure about the specific show you reference, but keep in mind that this type of 'low-level' reality show does attract a certain amount of fraud. The show 'storage wars', for example, had many claims of fraud leveled against it, with the accusation that lockers were filled up with valuables before being 'opened for the first time'.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad.  How can we address a persons intentions for a very small population?  This is an impossible question to answer.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon thanks for the words of caution. I'm not asking about that show specifically. I have seen abandoned vehicles in the outdoors myself when I lived in the US.

Comment: @CapeCode I presume you've driven past my parent's yard...

Comment: I'd say for a lot of people who do this, it's a form of [hoarding](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hoarding-disorder/symptoms-causes/syc-20356056).

Comment: Whatever the causes, I doubt it's all that frequent statistically. It's just bound to happen occasionally even with a low probability when you have hundreds of millions of people and millions of cars in the history of the U.S.

Comment: Basically it's *hoarding*, as @JimmyJames suggests, plus plain old *depression* (of which hoarding is a symptom).

Comment: @jpmc26 - But of course it's not just cars.  People hoard many other things.  Cars are simply more obvious.

Comment: I inherited my '65 356C coupe, will never sell it due to sentimental reasons.  Hasn't run in 12 years, sitting in my front yard.  When my roof was re-done the code person came out to inspect it and mentioned that they frowned on "old worthless cars sitting in yards".  I then pointed out that my old rusty Porsche was worth more than the relatively new Ford Ranger pickup the code guy was driving.  One day I'll have teh $ to restore it.....

Comment: The premise of the question is off. The OP is assuming that many people *intentionally* leave cars abandoned in a barn to rot. I doubt that's the case ever.

Comment: `It seems to be quite frequent in the USA` Is this really true? Or does 3 TV shows where this happens - finding 25 cars in this situation... (or however many are really found)... out of ~400 million people... is a few dozen cars REALLY that frequent?

Comment: A relative of mine in Eastern Europe had 3 - 4 cars in his barn. 2 of them were the same make/model, he was planning to use one of them for parts. Then he bought another one he was planning to give to his kid but she moved to the city and didn't need to drive so the car just sat. None of the cars were worth very much to begin with and after a while they were close to worthless so he preferred to keep them instead of selling them.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the cash flow pattern of the behavior. The vehicle is already bought. It may take some significant fixes, registrations or upgrades to make it salable. Just parking it in the barn has no cash cost. So if you are unsure what you want to do, the minimum cash outlay is to put it in the barn until you are ready to deal with it, which may never come.

Comment: Oooh, you really need to follow Jalopnik. There were a couple of articles recently that might lend some insight. One is ongoing: pretty much [a hoarder who's been instructed to sell 20 cars a month](https://jalopnik.com/michigan-man-forced-to-sell-20-cars-a-month-might-just-1818845024) from his land; another was a [1990 Corvette for $40,000](https://jalopnik.com/this-1990-corvette-zr-1-has-only-350-miles-1821552746) with only 350 miles on the clock, stored in a climate controlled facility. A better investment would have been a suitcase, with 56,000 dollar bills (purchase price). Answer? shrug!

Comment: @Rich: The investment value rather depends on timing, like anything else that's (potentially) collectible.  Back in the '70s, I rescued and rebuild several of those "barn find" cars, among them a Jaguar & Sunbeam Alpine.  Cost me a few hundred at the time: today examples are listed between $40K and $195K.

Comment: This is actually pretty common here in the US. I happen to have an `86 Lotus Turbo Espirit that belongs to a friend decaying in one of my barns right now.

Comment: "How come the owner decided to simply let a piece of property .. turn to dust?" Simple. We aren't all pure capitalists. For example, some are just too lazy for that.

Comment: @ivanivan Is it worth more *without restoration* than a new pickup? If it's not, then it's not.

Comment: @user20574 - last time I saw an unrestored project car sell it was $15k - and mine is in better shape and all parts are there.  So yeah... I'd say it is.  Probably worth more in parts than as a complete project car too...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If land is cheap with low opportunity cost for an alternative use (maybe you could pull an extra half bushel of corn or soybeans per year off a parking spot, or maybe not), so what?  At least you don't need to mow that patch.

If the vehicle starts to mechanically deteriorate (flat tires, dry rot on tires or hoses, condensation in the gas tank), you now have to incur some cost of time and/or money to get it off the property, in the form of fixing it up or hiring a tow truck.

If it doesn't drive, you don't have the time to fix it up and you don't need the space, the rational thing to do is not pay annual registration fees, adding an additional hump to overcome to get it moving again.

Comment: That’s a convincing argument. I guess since recycling is a relatively novel concept in the US, the price of the scrap metal was low enough that it wouldn’t cover the towing costs.

Comment: If you were going to take the time to find a recycler, you certainly could have found a buyer/taker-off-my-hands with a flatbed. Also keep in mind, at lot of places where barn finds exist are also places where space isn't a premium.

Comment: In this area, there are people who make a living from "scrapping". They put out signs, run newspaper ads and use social media to find sources. They will buy almost any vehicle, regardless of its condition. I have a friend who purchased a few acres of highway frontage that had an old garage and about 20 untitled vehicles on it. He made enough selling the vehicles to a scrapper to pay for the demolition of the buildings and having the lot cleared.

Comment: In addition to this, I've heard of people abusing the discounts that some insurers provide for insuring multiple cars with the insurer under a single policy.

Comment: @Gramatik that doesn't even make sense -- the discounted rate on two cars (one of which isn't even functional and may or may not be registered) is surely still more than the non-discounted rate on a single vehicle. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: As a farm owner, these vehicles usually end up in a place that would only be suitable for farming with significant work.

Answer (score 117):

> So, what are the financial motivations of people who buy cars and let them to rot?

Not every decision in life is based on financial motivations.

Say, for example, it's 1968 and you're tooling around in a 1965 Mustang, then get married and start to have kids.  The 'Stang is now highly impractical, but you love it and don't want to sell, so you stick it in the barn with the plan of having fun in the summer.

But... you never quite get around to it.  Busy with work, the pregnant wife doesn't want to ride in it and you feel guilty riding without her so leave it covered until next year.  *Wash, Rinse, Repeat* until "suddenly" it's 30 years later, covered in junk, and you've forgotten about it.

Another 30 years and your now-middle aged kids never knew it was there, and they sell the "farm" as part of splitting the estate now that you and your wife are dead.

The new owner cleans out the barn 10 years later and in 2030 finds a 1965 Mustang with only 15,000 miles on it.

Comment: Interesting. Still at some point somebody "forgets" that they own something that is worth several thousands of dollars.

Comment: @CapeCode people busy with life regularly forgot about 401(k) accounts from previous employers.  I remember a question on this site from a few months ago where a guy put **his paycheck** in a suit jacket pocket and forgot about it for many years.

Comment: @CapeCode It's only "worth" what someone will pay for it - either the owner didn't want to take the time and energy to sell it, or had a sentimental attachment.

Comment: It may be about convenience. When I moved into my house I inherited a bunch of "crap" (that's my term, not actual) in the basement. All I care about is getting the basement finished. Most of this stuff isn't in my expertise, taste, or era. There may be a priceless piece down there, but I would waste countless hours figuring this out, determining whether it's a reproduction or fake, etc; when I could pay someone a few hundred dollars to load it all up and see for themselves. Like @RonJohn said, "Not every decision in life is based on financial motivations." It always ain't about the money.

Comment: "Not every decision in life is based on financial motivations."  And very few automobile decisions _are_ based on financial motivations!

Comment: I think is the main real explanation: people don't intend to let cars rust in a barn, it just happens.

Comment: This answer is correct as far as it goes, but it doesn't explain [dead washing machines](https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/168442650/549944905/stock-photo-a-broken-washing-machine-in-an-old-abandoned-house-in-a-small-village-on-the-way-of-st-james-549944905.jpg) or the ubiquitous [toilets](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/53/49/0a/53490a08bfe74d95878e847e3afdf009--nepal-toilets.jpg) abandoned in yards.

Comment: @davidbak the question is "**forgotten** in **barns**", not "abandoned in yards".

Comment: I take your point. "Not every decision in life is based on financial motivations" applies to "forgotten in barns" but not "abandoned in yards", all decisions on objects abandoned yards are in fact financial.  (You know I'm just kidding around, I hope.)

Comment: I was cleaning up a stack of old records the other day, and shredding old documents, etc.  As I was going through the pile, I found an uncashed 13 month old escrow refund check for $65.  *How did I not remember getting this??!* Now I have to go through the hassle of returning the check and writing a letter to the bank to re-issue the check because of it's vintage.  This answer resonates with me because, well, let's face it, sometimes you just forget stuff!

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 my first thought when reading your comment was to wonder why you were *cleaning old records* (aka **vinyl**) while shredding old documents...  LOL

Comment: @CapeCode They don't need to "forget".  Anything mechanical will stop working if it's left.  After 10 years in the barn, the effort (and cost) to get it running again will be significant.  And whilst for us they're priceless 50-year-old antiques, in 1970 they were 10-year-old rustbucket clunkers, and they'll stay rustbucket clunkers in the mind of their owner.  He may not forget, but it won't be on anyone else's mind.

Comment: This is exactly how musical instruments of all price ranges and quality levels get left to rot in storage.

Comment: Exactly this. At the very least, it is what happened to me. I got busy with "life" and let a classic icon sit in a garage that did bad things to it. Years went by. It was covered, so easy to ignore (as one might do for something that has been neglected and in need of attention). One could easily imagine it becoming a garage find years later. Fortunately, with well-deserved spousal prodding I was able to correct the problems with the garage and get the car fixed up. Now I'm able to drive it a few times a year, take it to some car shows, and actually enjoy it.

Answer (score 34):

I'm not a psychologist, so I can't really speak as to the motivations, but I think it often boils down to "someday, but not today".  Take for instance my neighbor: he's a now-retired professional auto mechanic who worked for years restoring antique & classic cars.  So he has on his property a '60s Chevy that he's going to restore for his son* someday, a '70s Camaro that he he's going to restore for his wife someday, a motor home that he's going to restore so they can go camping someday... But today he's going to sit in front of the TV and drink beer :-(

*Now married with a couple of kids, and doing well enough to just buy whatever car he wants.

Comment: Everyone has dreams!

Comment: A dream is something you never intend to really do. As described above. Otherwise, it's a goal :)

Answer (score 22):

I have two cars, two boats, four personal water craft, two tractors, several ATVs and a dune buggy stored in various buildings around my place. They all ran when then were stored, and they all have a different story.

One car is the first car I ever purchased myself, a 1982 Chevy Z28 pace car. It's been at least 15 years since I parked it in the barn and covered it. The other is a 1966 (the year I was born) Corvette convertible I bought it in the late 90s with the intention of restoring it. I drove it one day, then had it stored in the barn also (it was professionally prepped for storage and is stored off the ground). I  just have never taken the time to do anything with either of them.

I bought a ski boat years ago and kept the bass boat for the kids to use. Then we bought a cruiser and kept the ski boat for the same reason. Kids are grown and have their own boats so these have sat under cover for years.

The first pair of PWCs were kept for the kids as well when we bought the new ones. We just haven't used the new ones in the last few years. Same thing with the rest of it all.

There was never a point where we made a decision on any of them, other than when we purchased them. We just stopped using them and moved on. They aren't in our way, and they're all stored in barns or other buildings around here, so they're not an eyesore. That means there isn't any reason to waste time dealing with them. They will likely remain where they are until this place and everything here is auctioned, either when we die or when we move to Colorado.

I almost forgot, at one point years ago I did decide to sell the Chevy so someone could drive it or restore it, but after wasting several hours with two different guys (one of them didn't have money and wanted me to let him make payments; the other complained about everything, the paint being faded, the carpet being worn, it only having lap belts and no shoulder belts, etc., until I ran him off) I realized it wasn't worth my time.

This was my personal experience. I can't say if this is a common reason for it, but I think it likely is.

Comment: Just curious, do you prefer owning these vehicles instead of renting them for the period you want to use them?

Comment: @CapeCode At that time, yes, we wouldn't have considered renting. It is too much of a hassle. Loading and unloading personal gear, having set times to pickup and return, and having to plan ahead and make reservations. Now we just keep a cruiser in a slip, which is the most convenient way to do it On the occasion when we want a smaller boat for a few days to ski or fish, all it takes is one call to the marina and they'll have one ready to go in our guest slip when we get there. 

We haven't rented anything else other than cars when we fly.

Answer (score 14):

Americans are rich.

No not all of them, but enough of them.  They can afford to buy a car worth 10s of 1000s of dollars (in todays money), and park it in a barn.

Maybe they intended to restore it or modify it.  Or maybe they had kids and it wasn't a practical car, so they bought a more practical one and only drove it rarely.  Maybe they took it out on special occasions, but those became rarer and rarer, and one day they had to change the oil or a tire or something and said "ok, not this time" and didn't get back to it.

Sure they could have sold it, but they didn't bother; they liked the car, they loved the image they had of working on it, they intended to work on it with their kids sometime (but their kids didn't want to mayhap).

The person is rich (compared to most of the world), land is cheap (relatively), and people get attached to cars.  So they pack it up to preserve it for when they "get back to it".

Life is short, and you don't always get back to things.

Comment: As an American, +1. Land ownership, the prerequisite for this whole thing, almost always means some level of wealth in the US, even in the middle of the country where land is (relatively) cheap.

Comment: @Justin Lardinois: Not necessarily, unless you count the potential value of the land itself.  There are a good number of people who inherit family land, like farms or other property, over several generations.  The current owners can be land rich but cash poor, barely able to scrape enough to pay the taxes.

Comment: It seems cheap land and lack of regulations to prevent pollution and blight are more likely explanations. The people keeping these carcasses aren't "rich" by Western standards.

Answer (score 8):

My grandpa's backup car broke down. It got shoved in the back of the garage. On cleaning up his estate and getting the house ready for rental we finally sold it. The needed repair was trivial. We guess he would have got it done had the primary ever failed. It was interesting to note the buyer repaired it on site and drove it out the day he bought it. As it was essentially worthless model it ended up in demolition derby.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a decision but rather a lack of decision.

Recycling your old car would **cost** you **your time**. It can also cost you **money**, for transport and utilization fees. You **might** get some money back (spare parts, raw material) which **might** be more than the costs you have to pay, or might be less. In any case, you invest your time...

If you expect to pay more than you could get, letting the car rot in the backyard is the cheap option. If you expect to get more, but the sum is not very relevant to you and you are relatively lazy, you simply don't care.